# How do I use the `join` UNIX command? Nothing is ever output

Tags: macos, unix, join, command-line-interface

I feel like I'm misunderstanding a very basic part of the `join` command, because I cannot get it to work (running OS X).

```
echo "testing" > 1.txt
echo "text" > 2.txt
join 1.txt 2.txt
```

No output.

Shouldn't it have "testing text" as the result?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a join because you don't have 'matching fields'.  You need something like

```
echo "1 testing" > 1.txt
echo "1 text" > 2.txt
join 1.txt 2.txt
```

to create `1 testing text` because it 'joins' (or matches) on the `1`

Answer (score 2):

For what you're trying to do, use `paste`, not `join`:

```
> echo "testing" > 1.txt
> echo "text" > 2.txt
> paste 1.txt 2.txt
testing text
```